# No Data 3G or 4G

Tags: internet

I live in India with a 3G data connection with a non rooted Yu yureka.From yesterday afternoon Mobile data does not work.Only those uparrow and that downarrow no H or LTE. So unable to connect to the world Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Try Switching airplane mode on or Off
check u have Data left.
contact your service provider and they could give u the configuration messages again. and try changing the apn names(Goto>Setting>More>Mobile networks>Access Point Names> select any of the one)

best of luck

Comment: 1)Airplane mode(nope, didn't work).  (2)Data Left(2.4Gb more).  (3)Apn(Reset to default then rebooted still no help). (4)Contact Aircel(I will try)

Comment: I checked the sim in my fathers mobile it worked.But not in my mobile.

Comment: Please tell me what the people of aircel  told u to do.

Comment: they said it is handset problem